# Excel Hyperlink macro error Runtime 1004 Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am creating an excel with multiple hyperlinks on the dashboard sheet. Clicking on one link opens another sheet with records filtered and other reset the filter.

It works for couple of links while fails for few with error:Runtime 1004 Application-defined or object defined error.

Links working: Cell I11, I14
Links throwing error: B11, E11.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-gwvoyXA0G0aUJZU3pIM3ZtVWM 
is the sample macro enabled excel for reference

**Code below:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)    
  Dim rngOpenTickets As Range  
  Dim rngMaxAge As Range  
  Dim rngPlannedFuture As Range  
  Dim rngTotalFuture As Range  

  Set rngOpenTickets = Range("TicketsOpen")  
  Set rngMaxAge = Range("TicketMaxAge")  
  Set rngPlannedFuture = Range("FuturePlanned")  
  Set rngTotalFuture = Range("TotalFuture")  

 If Target.Range.Name = rngPlannedFuture.Name Then  
    ApplyFilter 5, "<>"  
 ElseIf Target.Range.Name = rngMaxAge.Name Then  
    ApplyFilter 10, rngMaxAge.Text  
 ElseIf Target.Range.Name = rngTotalFuture.Name Or Target.Range.Name =   rngOpenTickets.Name Then  
     RemoveFilter  
  End If  
End Sub  

Sub RemoveFilter()  
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then  
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData  
    End If  
End Sub

Sub ApplyFilter(field As Integer, criteria As String)  
    Selection.AutoFilter  
    Selection.AutoFilter field:=field, Criteria1:=criteria  
End Sub
```

Need some help in resolving this. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Post the relevant part(s) of the code in your question.

Comment: at which line does your code error out?  Some guessing: 1) is `Target` a valid named range reference? is `Selection` always a valid one?

Comment: It errors at  If Target.Range.Name = rngPlannedFuture.Name, even though the link clicked is for range rngOpenTickets. It works for range rngPlannedFuture  and rngTotalFuture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the links in cell `I11`, `I14` vs `B11`, `E11` is as follows:

In `I11`, `I14` the links were set first and then the cells `I11:J11`, `I14:J14` were merged.

In `B11`, `E11` the cells `B11:C11`, `E11:F11` were merged first and then the links were set to the merged cells.

So in `B11:C11`, `E11:F11` the link `Target` is the merged range while in `I11`, `I14` the link `Target` is the single cell. Thats why `Target.Range.Name` fails with `B11:C11` and `E11:F11`.

It will work for both - merged cells link target and single cell link target -, if you take `Target.Range.Item(1).Name` instead.

```
  If Target.Range.Item(1).Name = rngPlannedFuture.Name Then
    ApplyFilter 5, "<>"
  ElseIf Target.Range.Item(1).Name = rngMaxAge.Name Then
    ApplyFilter 10, rngMaxAge.Text
  ElseIf Target.Range.Item(1).Name = rngTotalFuture.Name Or Target.Range.Item(1).Name = rngOpenTickets.Name Then
     RemoveFilter
  End If
```